# in neo4j's cypher, is there a way to obtain the property keys of a node?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The neo4j manual gives a good example for listing all property keys using the REST API:

```
:GET /db/data/propertykeys
```

Can this be achieved by using cypher only? maybe for one specific node as well?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since Neo4j 2.2 there's the [`keys`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-functions-collection.html#functions-keys) function. Example:

```
MATCH (n:Person{name:'Ernesto'}) RETURN keys(n)
```

Comment: Now I'm waiting for a similar function that will return the values of those keys, maybe as a map (feature feature!)

Comment: @stefan-armbruster How to get values corresponding to these keys ?

Comment: There's not a function for this, but you can use `[x in keys(n) | n[x]]`

Answer (score 6):

To get all distinct properties of all the nodes and relationships in neo4j database we can write something like

`MATCH (n) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() RETURN distinct keys(n), keys(r)`

Comment: This is somehow a more complete answer given that I didn't specify nodes only. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Neo4j 4:

```
CALL db.propertyKeys()
```

Here is the [manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/procedures/#procedure_db_propertykeys):

[image]